Textbook Recommendations on BFGS Quasi-Newton method in Optimization Problems
I'm trying to learn the BFGS update of the quasi-Newton method in optimization problems. I asked here because I've looked up some references on that topic, but I couldn't find one that discusses it thoroughly. To estimate the Heston model parameters (related to financial mathematics) using maximum likelihood estimation (related to statistical inference), I eventually will need to maximize the log-likelihood function, and I would have a good justification to use the quasi-Newton method to optimize the negative log-likelihood function if I can understand that method (along with the BFGS update) thoroughly. Any recommendations and suggestions are accepted. Thank you!

Hi: This looks pretty good for a summary-intuitive viewpoint. And it's got all the detailed references at the bottom when you want all the specifics.  https://towardsdatascience.com/bfgs-in-a-nutshell-an-introduction-to-quasi-newton-methods-21b0e13ee504

@markleeds I've been reading it and looked up the references it used. Thanks for recommending! Perhaps, do you have more recommendations, maybe a textbook except Wright's Numerical Optimization?

Hi: I hope it helped.  Optimization is not really my field  so the only other book I can recommend with confidence is Boyd's text. But that doesn't deal with derivative free as far as I can remember. ( I could be wrong there ). If you have Nocedal and Wright, I think you're pretty good. Hopefully others can say something cause like I said, I'm speaking from years ago.

Hi vszuvszu: I just went to amazon and searched for "derivative-free optimization". A lot of books came up but I have no idea about the good-ness of each. So, do that and maybe check a few of those out.

@markleeds Thanks a bunch for the advice, Mark! I will look it up. Have a good day.

you're welcome. glad if it helped a little.
